# Undefined reference to 'function' using CodeBlocks

Tags: c, compiler-errors, undefined-reference

I have the following error with a simple project to start learning with CodeBlocks.

```
E:\CodeBlocks\Projects\Triplet-CLEON-Benjamin\main.c|5|undefined reference to `initTriplet'|
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe: E:\CodeBlocks\Projects\Triplet-CLEON-Benjamin\main.c|7|undefined reference to `AfficheTriplet'|
```

I have only 3 files in my project, which are the following:

**main.c**

```
#include "triplet.h"

int main()
{
    triplet myTriplet = initTriplet(5,8,7);

    AfficheTriplet(myTriplet);

    return 0;
}
```

**triplet.c**

```
#include "triplet.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void AfficheTriplet(triplet myTriplet)
{
    printf("Triplet: \n\t Premier %d\n\t Second %d\n\t Troisieme %d", myTriplet.p, myTriplet.d, myTriplet.t);
}

triplet initTriplet(int a, int b, int c)
{
    triplet myTriplet = {a,b,c};

    return myTriplet;
}
```

**triplet.h**

```
#ifndef TRIPLET_H_INCLUDED
#define TRIPLET_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct triplet triplet;
struct triplet
{
    int p;
    int d;
    int t;
};

triplet triTripletV1(triplet myTriplet);
void    triTripletV2(triplet myTriplet);

void AfficheTriplet(triplet myTriplet);
triplet initTriplet(int a, int b, int c);

#endif // TRIPLET_H_INCLUDED
```

In my main file, if I include triplet, running works else if I include triplet.h I have the previous errors.

Also, my project is built as

- ProjectName

  - Sources

    - main.c
    - triplet.c
  - Headers

    - triplet.h

Any help, please?

Comment: Please show your compiler instruction.

Comment: Also I doubt whether it is allowed to use `triplet` both as typedef-name and as struct tag. In any case, this is bad practice. You can just write `typedef struct { ... } triplet;` instead.

Comment: Instead of `#include "triplet.h"` try `#include "Headers/triplet.h"`

Comment: include ```Headers/triplet.h```give me "No such file or directory

Comment: @Kolodez I don't know where is my compiler instruction, just using Build button.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any problem compiling your application in CodeBlocks, so probably the problem is that the header and source files are not part of your project. If you have already created a project, then you can try the following:

1. Open up your project (*.cbp)
2. Click on the tab called "Project"
3. Click on "Add files..."
4. Select all of your source and header files (triplet.c & triplet.h)
5. Click on "Open"
6. Build your project

Comment: I have the same error, sry

Comment: @BenjiHS Did you add the files to the project as a class? If yes, then it could be your problem. For C you should use File -> New -> Empty File to add new files to your project instead. 
Just out of curiosity, you can try to compile the same project that worked perfectly fine for me:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pukkqygtykh8dvw/Triplet.zip?dl=1

Comment: @BenjiHS Just one more thing. If you try to compile my project files, then you would need to do the above-mentioned process in my answer for it to work. Otherwise, you will get the same error message that you posted.

Comment: Ok, it was just a setting problem, I'll explain below

Answer (score 0):

I found answer, it was just a setting error...

In option of my files, I must had:

- main.c => Compile file and link file
- triplet.c => Compile file and link file
- triplet.h => no one

And if I do right click -> properties -> build on a file on each file, I have to be sure that Debug checkbox is checked.

Comment: Could you mark your own answer as an accepted solution, then?